# Remove one occurrence of an item in a list containing many occurrence

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

In my app I have a class that contains a list of these items:

```
public class Order
{
    (...)
    public List<OrderDetailInfo> mListOrderDetail { get; set; } 
}
```

And an orderDetail if shaped like this:

```
public class OrderDetailInfo
{
    public int mOrderDetailID { get; set; }
    public int mOrderDetailName { get; set; }
    (...)
}
```

In a place in my app I have to fill this list with empty stuff. So I create a bunch of "false" orderDetails object which all have the same id: 9999. I do this because this order needs to be confirmed later on.

Precisely, when this order is confirmed, I need to remove a set number of items based on the user's input and replace them with other he created. So I tried to do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < _itemQuantity; i++)
{
    var emptyJug = order.mListOrderDetail.SingleOrDefault(
            _item => _item.mInventoryID == 9999);

    order.mListOrderDetail.Remove(emptyJug);
}
```

But the line crashes when the "var emptyJug" line is hit because there can be many occurrences . I need to remove one unit of emptyJug from the list until the _itemQuantity is reached. How could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `FirstOrDefault` insted of `SingleOrDefault`.

`FirstOrDefault()` is for when zero or more results are expected to be present in the collection. Call to this method  returns the first item if there are multiple results, Default if none.

`SingleOrDefault()` is for when zero or one result is expected in the input collection. Call to this method returns the one result if exactly one result is present, Default if no results and **exception if more than one result.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using "FirstOrDefault" instead of "SingleOrDefault".